# ZF2 - Dynamic ViewHelper

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I want to create a view helper which should return some HTML like that:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        :: Here is my content ::
    </div>
</div>
```

The plan is to call it like the following, where the parameter should be a key in my config, which defines a view helper class to generate the content of my panel:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->panel('test');

    $config = [
        'view_helpers' => [
            'factories' => [
                'Panel' => 'Application\View\Helper\Factory\PanelFactory',
                'Test' => 'Application\View\Helper\Factory\TestFactory'
            ]
        ],
        'panels' => [
            'test' => 'Test'
        ]
    ];
?>
```

So I could load every content of a custom view helper into a panel, but I would have to inject the view helper manager in my panel view helper to load the wanted view helper from my config. Would that be correct or is there a better solution?

Comment: You can inject Config in your ViewHelper. Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should have a look at [ZF2 partials](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html). If I am not mistaken the partial view helper seems to be doing what you want.

You define a template (`panel.phtml`):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo $this->content ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the view where you want to output your panel partial:

```
$this->partial('panel.phtml', array(
    'content' => 'Whatever content you prefer (can also be another partial)'
);
```

You can register your partials like you would register any other view inside your template map in the view helper config:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'         => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'header'                => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
        'footer'                => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/footer.phtml',
        'error/404'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        'panel'                 => __DIR__ . '/../view/partial/panel.phtml',
        'test'                  => __DIR__ . '/../view/partial/test.phtml',
    )
)
```

Seems an easy solution to what you want to achieve. 
 
Or do you have other demands?

Comment: @DominikBarann Is this not what you want? Or did it solve your issue?